# Mysql query for specific date and time range

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

i have table like this

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+
|  Job   | jobRegisterTime  |  Job done time   |
+--------+------------------+------------------+
| job 1  | 2020-09-01 19:28 | 2020-09-02 10:28 |
| job 2  | 2020-09-02 09:28 | 2020-09-02 19:28 |
| job 3  | 2020-09-02 09:28 | 2020-09-02 10:28 |
| job 4  | 2020-09-04 09:28 | 2020-09-05 10:28 |
| job 5  | 2020-09-05 09:28 | 2020-09-05 10:28 |
| job 6  | 2020-09-12 09:28 | 2020-09-12 16:28 |
| job 7  | 2020-09-13 09:28 | 2020-09-13 10:28 |
| job 8  | 2020-09-14 09:28 | 2020-09-14 19:28 |
| job 9  | 2020-09-15 09:28 | 2020-09-16 10:28 |
| job 10 | 2020-09-16 19:28 | 2020-09-17 10:28 |
| job 11 | 2020-09-17 15:28 | 2020-09-18 05:28 |
| job 12 | 2020-09-12 09:28 | 2020-09-12 09:58 |
+--------+------------------+------------------+
```

And i don't know how write good query. Condition first part count all jobs in date range between register time all month for examples 2020-09-01 and 2020-09-30 this one easy i will use where and between. Second part is to filter jobs which was done in 2hours between work hours from 8h to 17h. The problem is i need include jobs like this example if job registered at 16h and done next day until 9h it counts, because after works hours like zero until next work day.

Few examples more:

```
Register time | Done time
2020-09-16 19:28 | 2020-09-17 9:28 = counts (Because it registered after work and done next day in work hours done 9:28 - 8:00 = 1:28
2020-09-16 11:28 | 2020-09-16 19:28 = doesn't count( range more than two hours)
2020-09-15 15:30 | 2020-09-16 08:30 Counts (because exclude not work hours. Difference 17:00 - 15:30 = 1:30 and 8:30 - 8:00 = 0:30 1:30 +0:30 = 2:00h
```

Can someone help to write correct condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do something like this to get the job duration excluding 16:00 - 08:00. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJUhydQkhfwKkjqhCQPN7b/0)

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN DATE(jobDoneTime) > DATE(jobRegisterTime) 
        THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,jobRegisterTime,jobDoneTime)- 16*60
        ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,jobRegisterTime,jobDoneTime) END duration_minutes,
        Job, jobRegisterTime, JobDoneTime 
  FROM  job
```

But your data has some edge cases, where the start and.or end time lie outside 08:00 - 16:00 .  You probably need to work out what you want in those case.

Comment: nice one almost what i need how can i use duration_minutes below from in where clause? got this error #1054 - Unknown column 'duration_minutes' in 'where clause'

Comment: and duration minutes doesn't match result